# Failed to compile in Vue 2 and Webpack.

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I just tried to install [Vue-double-list][1] in my Vue app. 
I have a fail to compile Webpack, but I do not know how resolve it. 
I use postcss.

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
      'postcss-loader'
    ],
  },      {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      postcss: [require('postcss-cssnext')()],
      loaders: {
      }
      // other vue-loader options go here
    }
  },
```

And it is the fail

```
   ./node_modules/vue-double-list/index.js
   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:20)
   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
   | export default from './dist/vue-double-list.common'
   | export * from './dist/vue-double-list.common'
   | import './dist/vue-double-list.css'
   @ ./src/main.js 11:0-41
   @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev- 
   server ./src/main.js
```

Comment: How you installed the package "vue-double-list" ?what version of "vue-double-list" that you have included in your package.json?

Comment: "vue-double-list": "^0.1.0",

Comment: installed with command "npm install vue-double-list " ?

Comment: Yes, I did it...

Comment: looks like this  has nothing to do with your webpack loaders.Error message directly coming from the module itself right?. So try re-installing the npm package "vue-double-list" by commands "npm uninstall vue-double-list","npm install vue-double-list"

Comment: Hi. I just did it, however, I have the same error. Maybe this plugin is no update or not working correctly. Do you know another plugin for make a Dual-list with Vue 2? I will be very grateful!